# How can I use touch input for 3rd-person controls?

Tags: c#, unity, touch, control

I have a 3rd-person controller in my Unity scene, which I can only control with the *WASD* buttons. But since I plan to make a smartphone game, I wonder how I can change these controls t *swipe up/down/right/left* and (if possible) keep *WASD* for debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Do this in character controller script's `Update()`

First of all you have to detect the user input via touch(begin/moved/ended) methods and then you have to calculate the gesture it ended up in like swipe-left.
You can assign a bool to it like `SwipeL = true;`

Now you have to add a condition in the methods where character movement is mapped with `Input.GetKey("A")` etc and append your `bool` with OR condition

e.g.

```
if(Input.GetKey("A") || SwipeL)
{
//code for moving left
}
```

You need to do this for all key mappings.

Comment: Great! Thank you. Unfortunately though, the 3rd Person Controller-Script is written in Javascript

Comment: @IMX Your question is not tagged with a specific language. And this answer is just showing an example. The technique described can be implemented in any language Unity supports.

Comment: `if` statements in javascript and c# are analogous for the purpose of this example